# Small GLFW application makes my desktop env. very slow, can it be fixed?

Tags: c++, performance, ubuntu, glfw

I'm building and running the small GLFW application introduced here:
http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html

The application seems to run fine, but changing/moving/resizing windows (note: not just the application, any window on my computer) while the application is running makes the X Window server (xorg) assume 100% CPU and the desktop environment becomes unearably sluggish.

Is this a bug with GLFW? Or Ubuntu? Can I fix it in the code somehow?

Thanks

**EDIT:** To clarify, the sluggish performance (high CPU usage) **only** occurs when I change/move/resize windows. If I leave the application running without doing anything, CPU usage is normal.

Comment: The code appears to be essentially a "busy rendering" loop so it's not surprising it maxes out a cpu.  It's a long time since I've used glfw but you might experiment with using [`glfwWaitEvents`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga554e37d781f0a997656c26b2c56c835e) rather than [`glfwPollEvents`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga37bd57223967b4211d60ca1a0bf3c832).

Comment: Thanks, but removing `glfwPollEvents` doesn't make the application run any better. Also, I should have clarified that CPU usage is normal as long as I don't change/move/resize any windows.

Comment: @G.M. Also, `glfwSawpBuffers` seems to halt the loop, so the loop doesn't seem to max out CPU. Unless perhaps triggering some events causes `glfwSwapBuffers` to cancel halting (causing the loop to free-wheel)...